# How to stop .click function being fired many times if user clicks many times

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to stop `.click()` function being fired many times if user clicks many times.

Here is my code

```
$("#loadme").unbind('click').click(function() {
  hello();
});
```

If the user clicks on `#loadme` many times the function will repeat again and again. I want it to stop firing it many times.

Comment: Why are you binding the `click` handler multiple times in the first place?

Comment: The question isn't clear but maybe you want [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Answer (score 4):

You seem to want [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) :

```
$("#loadme").one('click', function(){
   hello();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var clicked = false;

$("#loadme").unbind('click').click(function(){
    hello();
    clicked = true;
});

function hello(){
    if(clicked){
        //do nothing because it was clicked more than once.
    }else{
        //your code
        clicked = false; //reset
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
$("#loadme").on("click",function(){
    $("#loadme").off("click");
    hello();
});
```